# How to update drupal/core-recommended from 9.0.11 to 9.1.4?

Tags: 9

I did
composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies
and this got the site updated to 9.0.11.

In Available Updates Drupal is recommending 9.1.4. What composer command will get me there with drupal/core-recommended?

Composer.json is

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap4": "^2.1",
        "drupal/bootstrap_layouts": "^5.2",
        "drupal/coffee": "^1.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.9",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
        "drupal/hierarchical_term_formatter": "^1.2",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/shs": "^1.0",
        "drupal/stage_file_proxy": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_bootstrap": "^4.3",
        "drush/drush": "^10.3"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your composer.json to the question? Many thanks 

Comment: I just did a `composer install` on the provided json file and got 9.1.4. So everything seems to be OK and compatibel. You could try running just `composer update`?

Comment: Run `composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-dependencies` and add it as answer if it's working. You need to ensure to update all core packages you have in the composer.json.

Comment: So I tried composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-dependencies
Composer output says
- updating drupal/core-composer-scaffold (9.0.6 => 9.1.4): Downloading 100%
- updating drupal/core-project-message (9.0.6 => 9.1.4: Downloading 100%
So then I did
drush updb
drush cr
Status report is still saying 9.0.11

Comment: The solution was - delete composer/semver from composer.json. Then run
composer update drupal/core "drupal/core-*" drush/drush --with-all-dependencies
Thanks to Dave Long on Drupal/ddev Slack

Answer (score -2):

try This is working with me :

```
 composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies
```

if not working try this at composer.json :

```
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1",
```

After change Run:

```
    composer install or update
```

Comment: I tried this and composer install updated the site to drupal core 9.1.0-alpha1, which says there is a security update required.

Comment: I changed composer.json to "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1.4" (and the other 2). This gives drupal/core-recommended 9.1.4 requires composer/semver 3.2.2 -> satisfiable by composer/semver[3.2.2].
$ composer require composer/semver:3.2.2 which gives drupal/core-recommended 9.1.0-alpha1 requires composer/semver 1.7.1 -> satisfiable by composer/semver[1.7.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.